# How can I use regex to get command and arguments from a discord message with the (optional) user at the end

Tags: javascript, regex, discord.js

I'm building a bot that will take commands through Discord Channels like "!COMMAND Some Thing With Spaces In The Name <@123412341234>"

I need a regex expression that, while using javascript, will allow me to get the following:

```
const args = ["COMMAND", "Some Thing With Spaces In The Name", "<@123412341234>"];
```

OR, in the absence of the user mention at the end:

```
const args = ["COMMAND", "Some Thing With Spaces In The Name"];
```

I've tried using `(\S+)\s(.+)(\s<@\d+>)?` but what I get looks like:

```
const args = ["COMMAND", "Some Thing With Spaces In The Name <@123412341234>"];
```

I need the mention separate. What I'm most interested in is the COMMAND and the argument after it without the mention. Which could be in the command or not. I know I can get the mention by doing `message.mentions.users.first()`. That's not really what I'm after.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use `^(\S+)\s+(.*?)(?:\s+(<@\d+>))?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/V3Rhwm/1).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew for your response.

I tried it, and here's what I got:

```[
  'COMMAND Some Thing With Spaces In String <@!478745025275101185>',
  'COMMAND',
  'Some Thing With Spaces In String <@!478745025275101185>',
  undefined,
  index: 0,
  input: 'COMMAND Some Thing With Spaces In String <@!478745025275101185>',
  groups: undefined
]```

I ran the string with `.match(/^(\S+)\s+(.*?)(?:\s+(<@\d+>))?$/);`.

The mention still shows up on the third one and the fourth item is undefined.

Comment: So, my regex also works, right?

Comment: Yes, it also worked. Thank you. I was missing the !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use capturing groups, and then reference the capturing groups when constructing your strings.

Regex:

```
^!(\w+) (.+?)(?: |$)(<@\d+>)?$
```

- Capturing group 1 is "COMMAND"
- Capturing group 2 is "Some Thing With Spaces In The Name"
- Capturing group 3 is "<@123412341234>" only if it is present, otherwise capturing group 3 is undefined

Comment: So I tried this with `let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).match(/^(\w+) (.+?)(?: |$)(<@\d+>)?$/);` and got the <@123412341234> portion inside the 2nd group. Basically reading "Some Thing With Spaces In The Name <@123412341234>" with the last group (3) undefined.

Comment: Nevermind. This is the solution I was looking for. The discord mention starts with <@!, not <@. Once I added the missing exclamation it all worked perfectly. Thank you!